# UDP/IP Communation between apps

Tags: c#, networking, udpclient

I'm working on an app which using UDP/IP communication to send data to each other. But now it's using broadcasting.

```
    private void InitializeSender()
    {
        sendingClient = new UdpClient();
        sendingClient = new UdpClient(broadcastAddr, port);
        sendingClient.EnableBroadcast = true;
    }

    public void Sender(string message)
    {
         if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(message))
         {
                string toSend = yourUsername+":"+message;
                byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(toSend);
                sendingClient.Send(data, data.Length);
          }
     }
```

I want to switch it to dedicated sending. I have an `List<Dictionary<string, IPEndPoint>> user_ip = new List<Dictionary<string, IPEndPoint>>();` where I store the username and IP combination. But I dont know how to get these data from the other app. How to send username/IP information to the other client. Should I have a broadcasting discovery or something like that? Do you know any good solution for this?

Comment: Your app is not using TCP/IP, it's using UDP/IP...

Comment: Yes, it was just a misstype

Answer (score 0):

The simplest and durtiest solution:

1. Starting application listens on port A for usernames. Every incoming message with username inside will be put in `user_ip` dictionary alongside with sender's ip (except own username, ofc).
2. It broadcasts its own username on the same port A across the network. This step allows other instances which are already started to remember this new client's ip (as they are already listening to port A).
3. It starts answering to every incoming username with own username, and continue to put them into `user_ip`. Don't stop this behavior until application is shut down. That is why after step 2 application will receive (hopefully) a full list of clients on the same network.

There are two main problems with this solution:

1. UDP does not ensure message to be delivered, which makes entire product unreliable.
2. This approach does not work across the internet. To overcome this limitation you need a reachable server which will take care of synchronization. In combination with TCP this will also eliminate the first problem.

**UPD:**
Upon a question about choosing TCP vs UDP.

TCP provides reliability, UDP is considered to be faster (in some cases a LOT faster). So the correct choice depends.

Also keep in mind that TCP does not allow you to do broadcast. Actually that means with TCP you will basically have two choices:

1. Have a server
2. OR use UDP for peer discovery then use TCP to transfer actual data.

The latter option still lacks reliability on the very first step. BUT this flaw probably can bypassed by repeating step 2 periodically. lets say once every 5 minutes, which shoud be appropriate for the most of applications.

As you can see there is a LOT (really, much more than i mentioned here) possibilites, and the choise heavily depends upon an actual task. It is extremely hard to tell which way should you go as you did not describe any requirements.

Personally when not restricted i prefer to take a path of flexibility and choose the "client-server" architecture, because requirements always can change. When customer says "i need this to work across the internet" i am already there:) But this decision still heavily depends on actual task.

Comment: So should I use TCP protocol? Yes I don't want to work across the Internet yet. If I want to I'll use a server.

Comment: @SzabolcsMészáros updated my answer to address this point :) hope this helps.